# How to get socket.io working with ES6 import modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I refactored a simple example of socket.io from CommonJS `require` syntax to ES6 `import` syntax but when I start the server and go to the website, although it shows the HTML text ("test from server.js"), it doesn't inform the server that it is connected.

Yet there are no errors in the console at all, it just acts as if socket.io is not loading at all.

In my `package.json` file, I have the following entry in order that ES6 modules work in Node:

```
"type": "module",
```

Why is socket.io not working?

#### server.js

```
import path from 'path';
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express';
import { Server as socketIO } from 'socket.io';

const app = express();
const PORT = 5011;
const __dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(''));
const server = http.Server(app);
const io = new socketIO(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');
    socket.emit('greeting-from-server', {
        greeting: 'you loaded the page'
    });
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

#### /public/index.html

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
          content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Socket.IO</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io('http://localhost:5011');
        socket.on('greeting-from-server', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit('greeting-from-client', {
                greeting: 'Hello Server'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    test from server.js
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const httpServer = createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  // ...
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // ...
});enter code here

httpServer.listen(3000);
```

Comment: My intention was to get this working with Express, but your `createServer()` code here made me realize that I need to call listen not on `app` but on `server`. My express code works now. Thanks.

Comment: Answers like this with no text explanation at all as to what/why you fixed are a puzzle, requiring the reader to try to figure things out.  Please add explanatory text and what you changed and why and what the original problem was.

Comment: Why no explanation and some `enter code here` typo?